# $_GET Breaks XML

Tags: php, xml, flash, image

I'm using the SimpleViewer flash image gallery on a site, and it uses an XML file for information about the images it displays.

For the site, I need to dynamically generate the XML, so I'm using a PHP file with a text/xml Content-type declared. However, for some reason when I access one of the GET variables in the $_GET array SimpleViewer tells me that there are no images in the gallery, even though when I view the source it looks the exact same and is well-formed.

Here's the code:

```
$photos = array(
 "1" => array("house1_1.JPG")
);
foreach($photos[$_GET["hid"]] as $p){
 echo '';
}
```

If I replace `$_GET["hid"]` with `"1"` then it works fine, but when I make the reference to $_GET it returns the error.

Is there some reason as to why accessing a GET variable would cause scripts linking to the XML (the SimpleViewer flash) to malfunction, and is there a way to get around this?

*Note: The "hid" GET variable is 100% sure set to "1", and there is no PHP error.
Also, the output looks exactly the same for when I use $_GET["hid"] versus "1", the only difference is the SimpleViewer script refuses to see that the images are there.
Also, the stuff in the empty quotes is some XML, but I don't know how to get it to appear in the tags...

Var dump of $photos and $_GET, respectively:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "house1_1.JPG"
  }
}
array(1) {
  ["hid"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: What does the output look like in the non-functional case? Else please elaborate what "scripts linking to the XML" means.

Comment: You say that the XML is the same whether you use "1" or $_GET['hid'] - are you *sure*? Like, really, really sure?

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure. The XML is /exactly/ the same.

Comment: And you're looking at what SimpleViewer is seeing? Because what you're saying is that given exactly the same request producing exactly the same XML, SimpleViewer interprets it differently based on PHP internals that it cannot know about.

Comment: That's half the question. I don't really have a way of knowing how SimpleViewer interprets it, but I don't understand why SimpleViewer refuses to interpret it solely because it contains a reference to $_GET -- it's a part of the PHP, not a part of the XML.

Comment: I'd suggest logging the PHP request from SimpleViewer and outputing it to a file (including headers) and running a diff over them to find anything unexpected. There has to be a difference, but until you can state what the difference is we won't be able to help soz :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue was never resolved -- I ended up having to just move on and go for a longer and less elegant solution. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check and make sure $_GET["hid"] is returning "1".  If it's possible that it is not returning "1" then it should throw an error accessing a bad index of $photos.

Comment: There is no PHP error, and I'm sure that the "hid" is set to 1. Echoed and all.

Comment: Maybe check the type then of that variable and make sure it's a string and not an int?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `$_GET` `hid` variable set in your request? If not this will trigger a PHP warning.

`var_dump($_GET['hid']);` to see the value of the `$_GET` variable and ensure it as you expect.

Also please ensure that you have error reporting set to at least `E_ALL` and display errors is set to yes/true to make your debugging easier.

Comment: Absolutely sure that the "hid" variable is what I want it to be. Although, how do I change the error reporting?

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump()` of `$photos` and `$_GET` so we can see exactly what we are dealing with please.

Comment: Well that should be working. I cannot see anything wrong there. Have you tried renaming `hid` to something else less generic such as `WillsSuperFantasticGetParameter` just to ensure that the code you are interfacing with isn't toying with your variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably having an issue with the difference between "1" and 1. When you use a get with something like ?hid=1, it's not coming through as a string, that's being converted to a number, whereas your actual array is using the string "1" as the key.

Either change your key to 1 instead of "1" or cast the hid to string.

Comment: Nope, from the manual: 'if a key is the standard representation of an integer, it will be interpreted as such (i.e. "8" will be interpreted as 8, while "08" will be interpreted as "08")'

Comment: @Will: According to your `var_dump`, this is the actual problem. `$_GET['hid']` contains `'1'` (a string), while the index in the array is an integer `1`.

Comment: @poke it really isn't. If you don't believe me, try it out. $foo = array("1" => 'bar'); echo $foo[1]; // echos "bar"; Or the opposite: $foo = array(1 => 'bar');
echo $foo['1]; // echos "bar";